# Need help uploading a file separated by commas, spaces, and tabs

Tags: c++, parsing, ifstream

I am reading a file in that looks like this:

```
4

1 2 3,4

4, 5,     6 7

  8.0, 9, 10,    11, 8.0, 9, 10,          11
```

When I try to make it into a 4x4 matrix it looks like this:

```
1 2 3,4 4,

5, 6 7 8.0,

9, 10, 11, 8.0,

9, 10, 11 11
```

How do I get the input from the file to ignore the commas (include them as delimiters with the white space) found in the matrix?

```
//Declared variables
string filename;
int rows = 0;
string value;

//Declared file objects
ifstream data_input;

//Prompts user for filename
cout << "Please enter the name of the file that you would like to upload.\n";
cin >> filename;

//Opens the file.
data_input.open(filename);

//Set total number of rows and total number of columns for Matrix A
data_input >> rows;
int columns = rows;
vector<vector<string>> matrix(rows, vector<string>(columns));

//Goes through each row
for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
{
    //Goes through each column
    for (int j = 0; j<columns; j++)
    {
        //Sets values to a matrix
        data_input >> value;
        matrix[i][j] = value;
    }
}

//Prints out matrix
cout << "--------Matrix--------\n";
for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
{
    //Goes through each column
    for (int j = 0; j<columns; j++)
    {
        //Prints out each individual value of Matrix A
        cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

system("pause");
system("cls");
return 0;
```

Desired Output:

1 2 3 4

4 5 6 7

8.0 9 10 11

8.0 9 10 11

Comment: Please state your **question clearer**. It is unclear to me, what your **desired output** would be (please supply an **example**). Also your (seemingly wrong) output holds `11 11` which I can't read from your input. (Furthermore `values separated by commas and ignore the other commas` is pretty confusing to me.)

Comment: The output should be: (semi-colon denotes end of row)
1 2 3 4; 

4 5 6 7 ;

8.0 9 10 11; 

8.0 9 10 11 ;

I believe the 11 11 that you are talking about is just taking the last value that was read in from the file and sets it to the last spot on the matrix (matrix [4][4]). Does my question make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

When you read into a string, it stops when whitespace is encountered. To overcome your problem (since you have indefinite commas), first read the file line by line, replace all occurrences of comma to whitespace, then convert it into a vector. For instance

```
vector<vector<string>> matrix;
std::ifstream in(filename);
std::string line;
int rows;
in >> rows;
while (std::getline(in, line)) {
    std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ',', ' ');
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
    std::vector<std::string> vstrings(begin, end);
    matrix.push_back(vstrings);
}
```